# multiple waits in C\C++

Tags: c++, fork, wait

I have a program that can fork itself multiple times and at a users discretion.

I want to know when a child exits (and it's return status) while still trying to do something else.

I know that I can solve this with threads; however, I don't know if there is a `poll(2)` like function to check for variable changes (like a watchpoint).

As an **psudocode** example:

```
int counter = 0;
child()
{
  cout << "Hello World\n";
  return counter++;
}

int main()
{
  vector<pid_t> children;
  vector<int> status;
  char answer = 'y';

  while(answer != 'q')
  {
    cout << "create a new child?\n";
    cin >> answer;

    if(answer == 'y')
    {
      pid_t temp;
      temp = fork();
      if(temp == 0)
      {
         child();
      }
      else
      {
        //save the child's pid
        children.push_back(temp);
      }
    }
    int num_ready = 0;
    //wait to see if there was an event otherwise go back to user input
    if(( num_ready = poll(children, timeout)) > 0)
    {
      //loop through all ready children
      for( int x = 0; x < num_ready)
      {
        int temp_status = 0;
        //some way to know which child is ready
        waitpid(children, &temp_status, 0);
        status.pushback(temp_status);
      }
    }  
  }  
}
```

I know I *could* spawn a thread do `wait(&status)` and then try to narrow it down once something has changed and then inform the parent; however, I'd rather not have that overhead.

Comment: You can poll by doing `waitpid(..., WNOHANG);`. **Don't** spawn a thread to poll, mixing threads and processes is dangerous.

Comment: :( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281197/re-tagging-c-questions-as-c I'm actually writing in C, but I put C++ code for convince.

Comment: Get where you are coming from, but it's a dangerous game sometimes. You may get answers in C++ that cannot be applied to C and vice versa and then waste time trying them on for size. Best to stick to the target language.

Comment: Thanks @EOF...right there in front of me in the man pages. If you write as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @SailorCire: Not feeling like writing a C++ answer ;-P

Comment: I'm not going to change the title, because in this case, the answer is applicable to c or c++ (just swap vector for an array).

Comment: There is no language C/C++ (and none C\C++ either). Only the **different** languages C an C++.

Comment: @Olaf C++ inherits from C. I know there is a meta post about this; however, if the library is exactly the same <sys/wait.h> and can be used using the same exact code in two different languages, then the answer will be the same for them. Don't look at the wording, look at the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `wait(2)`:

```
       The value of options is an OR of zero or more of the following constants:

       WNOHANG     return immediately if no child has exited.

       WUNTRACED   also return if a child has stopped (but not traced via ptrace(2)).  Status for traced children which have stopped is provided even if this option is not specified.

       WCONTINUED (since Linux 2.6.10)
                   also return if a stopped child has been resumed by delivery of SIGCONT.
```

So, we can apply this to the above.

```
int counter = 0;
child()
{
  cout << "Hello World\n";
  return counter++;
}

int main()
{
  vector<pid_t> children;
  vector<int> status;
  char answer = 'y';

  while(answer != 'q')
  {
    cout << "create a new child?\n";
    cin >> answer;

    if(answer == 'y')
    {
      pid_t temp;
      temp = fork();
      if(temp == 0)
      {
         child();
      }
      else
      {
        //save the child's pid
        children.push_back(temp);
      }
    }
    //loop through all ready children
    for( auto &x : children)
    {
       int temp_status = 0;
      //some way to know which child is ready
      if(waitpid(x, &temp_status, WNOHANG) > 0)
      {
        status.insert(x, 1, temp_status);
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

If you're doing this in C then just replace the vector with an array.

Comment: You may not need to explicitly poll *every* child. `waitpid()` will return the pid of the child, so you can use a wildcard pid like `-1` and not need to loop over all children.